# If $S = \{x \in [0,1] \mid f(x) \neq0\}$ is a set, what is the complement of $S$, $S^{c}$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

If $S = \{x \in [0,1] \mid f(x) \neq0\}$ is a set, what is the complement of $S$, $S^{c}$?

Is it: $S^{c} = \{x \neq [0,1] \mid f(x) \neq0\} = \{x \in \{\mathbb{R} \setminus [0,1]\} \mid f(x) \neq0\}$

or

$S^{c} = \{x \in [0,1] \mid f(x) = 0\}$?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the universal set?  If it is $[0,1]$, then your second answer is correct.

Comment: If the universal set is $\mathbb{R}$, then your second set unioned with $\mathbb{R} - [0,1]$ is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x\in S\iff (x\in [0,1]) \wedge f(x)\neq 0$$
Therefore
$$x\in S^c\iff \neg (x\in [0,1] \wedge f(x)\neq 0)$$
$$\iff x\notin [0,1] \vee f(x)=0$$
$$x \in [0,1]^c\cup \{x:f(x)=0\}$$
As mentioned by  Paul Hurst in comments, $[0,1]^c$ depends on the universal set.